# $(a+b) ^2=a+b$ in rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Ok so my math teacher told us that $\sqrt {(a+b)}=\sqrt a+\sqrt b $ for all reals, which is clearly false. However when I told this to another math teacher he told me this was true for fields of characteristic 2. replacing that statement by this one which is more general $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2$Which I interpret as fields where $a+a=0$ for any a.

My new question is for rings in general, in which rings does it hold that $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2$ or in other words in what rings is $ab=-ba$ for all $a,b$?

Comment: $a^2=b^2+(a=b)^2$? Do you mean $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$?

Comment: I sense there is an error made in your simplification but I can't tell because of the $=$ signs. In general a ring need not even have square roots of elements.

Comment: Did my edit just now fix it to what you actually wanted?

Comment: this is what I should have typed

Comment: If the ring contains a unity, then $ab+ba =0$ implies $a+a = 0$ by setting $b = 1$, so the ring is of characteristic $2$. Conversely, any commutative unital ring of characteristic $2$ satisfies your property. For the remaining cases, I don't know...

Comment: Let me get this straight. Your **math teacher** told you that $\sqrt{a+b}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ for real numbers? You should seriously consider changing school.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be a unital ring such that $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$ for all $a, b \in A$. This is equivalent to $ab + ba = 0$ for all $a, b \in A$. Setting $b = 1_A$, you get that the ring is of characteristic $2$. Now in characteristic $2$, $ab + ba = 0$ can be rewritten as $ab = ba$, which means the ring is commutative.

Conversely, any commutative unital ring of characteristic $2$ satisfies your property.

You can extend this proof for any ring $A$ such that for all $a\in A$, there exists $e_A \in A$ such that $a e_a = a e_a = a$. As for the general case, I have no idea.

Comment: Srry why does ab+ba=0 imply ab=ba in characteristic 2?

Comment: Add $ba$ on both sides of the equality, you get $ab + 2 ba = ba$. But since $2ba = 0$ (you're in characteristic $2$), then $ab = ba$.

Answer (score 3):

If we are working in a commutative ring $R$,
$\sqrt{a+b}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ implies that $4ab=0$. If you want this latter equation to hold for all $a, b$, then you need $4=0$

Comment: $4$ is $1+1+1+1$. I don't understand the first part of your question.

Comment: I don't want to keep using the square root notation since not all elements in a ring must have a unique square root

Comment: Right. Some algebra gives the statement $4ab=0$ which one can ask of any elements. Then if you let $a=b=1$, you have $4=0$.

Comment: aren't you using commutatively for that?

Comment: Ah ok, yes. I thought you were interested in commutative rings. Let me think about the non-commutative case.

Comment: Take $a=b=1$ and square it. 2=(1+1)^2 implies 0=2.

Comment: @Alexander: 2= 4 implies 2-2 = 4-2

Comment: @JackSchmidt Ah right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is a $2$-dimensional vector space over an arbitrary field $k$, choose a basis $\{e_1, e_2 \}$ for $V$. Then, the subring of the exterior algebra $\wedge^*V$ generated by $e_1, e_2, e_1 \wedge e_2$ is such a noncommutative ring.